# Is it possible to include a module at runtime in an running Angular solution?

Tags: angular, extending, angular-ivy

I have a general Angular solution and I want to make it expandable for each user that has this general solution "installed". This means that it will have a screen where you can upload a module (some Angular code), and then this module/code will be available in the general solution that is running.

This will make it possible for each user running their own instance of the genereal soultion to custimize it without including it in the general solution.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: You can lazy load modules, but you wouldn't be able to add new routes/modules while it is running. Also it is dangerous to allow execution of uploaded code on your running solution.

Consider refactoring the bulk of the generalized solution into libraries that can be used by others.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! It is only the owner of the system that has the right to uploads those modules! When you suggest to lazy load modules, will it then be possible to make a module of some Angular code and compile it into some kind of a package. Then upload that package into the general soultion and integrate the module on a page in the genreal soloution ?